# Take a few elements from an iterable, do something, take a few elements more, and so on

Tags: python, python-itertools

Here is some python code moving data from one database in one server to another database in another server:

```
cursor1.execute(""" 
      SELECT d1.Doc_Id , d2.Doc_Id 
      FROM Document d1 
      INNER JOIN Reference r  ON d1.Doc_Id = r.Doc_Id 
      INNER JOIN Document d2 ON r.R9 = d2.T9
""")

cursor2.execute("START TRANSACTION")
cursor2.executemany( "INSERT IGNORE INTO citation_t(citing_doc_id, cited_doc_id) VALUES (?,?)",
    cursor1 )
cursor2.execute("COMMIT")
```

Now, for the sake of exposition, let's say that the transaction runs out of space in the target hard-drive before the commit, and thus the commit is lost. But I'm using the transaction for performance reasons, not for atomicity. So, I would like to fill the hard-drive with commited data so that it remains full and I can show it to my boss. Again, this is for the sake of exposition, the real question is below. In that scenario, I would rather do:

```
cursor1.execute(""" 
      SELECT d1.Doc_Id , d2.Doc_Id 
      FROM Document d1 
      INNER JOIN Reference r  ON d1.Doc_Id = r.Doc_Id 
      INNER JOIN Document d2 ON r.R9 = d2.T9
""")

MAX_ELEMENTS_TO_MOVE_TOGETHER = 1000

dark_spawn = some_dark_magic_with_iterable( cursor1, MAX_ELEMENTS_TO_MOVE_TOGETHER )

for partial_iterable in dark_spawn:
     cursor2.execute("START TRANSACTION")
     cursor2.executemany( "INSERT IGNORE INTO citation_t(citing_doc_id, cited_doc_id) VALUES (?,?)",
             partial_iterable )

     cursor2.execute("COMMIT")
```

My question is, which is the right way of filling in `some_dark_magic_with_iterable`, that is, to create some sort of iterator with pauses in-between?

Comment: You mean you want to *batch* results?

Comment: @MartijnPieters Yes, sort of...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just create a generator! :P

```
def some_dark_magic_with_iterable(curs, nelems):
    res = curs.fetchmany(nelems)
    while res:
        yield res
        res = curs.fetchmany(nelems)
```

Ok, ok... for generic iterators...

```
def some_dark_magic_with_iterable(iterable, nelems):
    try:
        while True:
            res = []
            while len(res) < nelems:
                res.append(iterable.next())
            yield res
    except StopIteration:
        if res:
            yield res
```

Comment: Hey! You are cheating! Normal iterators don't have 'fetchmany'. But your answer will certainly help in this case.

Comment: Normal iterators may not, but you're querying SQL and a cursor should have that :)

Comment: Super-thanks. I'm accepting your answer now. It is a pity there is no one-liner somewhere in the standard library...

Comment: Mmh... I thought there would be something in `itertools`, but I can't see anything :?